# Datatables free alternative editor

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

I setup Datatable like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/.
Then i add row and works perfect.

After this i load and reinit datatable with new columns and rows data and when i will add new row get i this error alert:

`DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unkwnown parameter '2' for row 1, column 2.`

This is my example:

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" id="saveTableBtn" style="display: none;">Save</button>
    <button type="button" id="loadTableBtn" style="display: inline-block">Load</button>
    <button type="button" id="loadTableBtn2" style="display: inline-block">Load 2</button>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="tableWrapper"></div>
</div>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myTable = null;
    var initTable = function(columns, data) {
        var tableId = "myTable";
        var dataSet = data;
        var columnDefs = columns;

        $("#tableWrapper table").remove();
        $("#tableWrapper").html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="' + tableId + '"><thead><tr>' + columns + '</tr></thead></table>');

        myTable = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            ajax: data,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
            select: 'single',
            responsive: true,
            altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
            destroy: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Add',
                    name: 'add'        // do not change name
                },
                {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Edit',
                    name: 'edit'        // do not change name
                },
                {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Delete',
                    name: 'delete'      // do not change name
                }
            ]

        });

        $("#saveTableBtn").css("display", "inline-block");

        $('#saveTableBtn').off().click(function() {
            console.log(myTable.rows().data());
        });
    }

    $("#loadTableBtn").click(function() {
        var dataSet = "data.json";
        var columnDefs = "<th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Extn.</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th>";

        initTable(columnDefs, dataSet);
    });

    $("#loadTableBtn2").click(function() {
        var dataSet = "data2.json";
        var columnDefs = "<th>Name</th><th>Position</th>";

        initTable(columnDefs, dataSet);
    });
});
</script>
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Probably it's not relevant to you any more, however I think your error might be caused due to you do not pass Row ID correctly. Please, see this [Row ID source specification](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/jsonId.html)